# How to find difference between large and small element in a specific row of an 2D array using C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Write a C program which can four cities temperature for last five days and display the difference between the highest and lowest temperature for each city

Sample Input

```
20 27 28 22
12 22 12 20
22 24 25 33
33 30 30 29
```

Sample Output

```
8
8
11
4
```

I was looking for the difference between large and small element in a particular row of an 2D array using C. I'm able to find large and small element but I'm kind of lost in between searching a particular row to find the difference between large and small element. Below I'm showing my piece of code -

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array1[10][10];
    int num, row, column;

    printf("How many rows and columns are needed: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);

    printf("\nHow many cities temperature you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter %d cities temperature: ", num);

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    int largeA = array1[0][0];
    int smallA = array1[0][0];
    int diff = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        int diff = 0;
        for(int j=1; j<column; j++)
        {
            if(array1[i][j] > largeA)
            {
                largeA = array1[i][j];
            }
            if(array1[i][j] < smallA)
            {
                smallA = array1[i][j];
            }
        }
        diff = largeA - smallA;
        printf("%d\n", diff);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of lost to find out the difference between large and small element in each row.

Comment: Shouldn't the second output be 10 not 8? Does the code you've posted not work? What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: How does the "kind of lost" manifest?

Comment: "Kind of lost" meaning that I'm trying to find the difference between large and small element in each row but in first row I get the correct answers but the rest of the rows get wrong answers.

Comment: you are ignoring the `num` variable

Comment: @Md.AsifImityajChowdhury your calculated differences in the example are wrong!

Comment: You need to reset `largeA` and `smallA` at the start of each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use functions. It makes code more readable, do not program in `main`
2. Use the correct type for indexes (size_t)
3. It will be much easier for you to avoid user input wnen you **test** your code. It will save you a lot of time spent on entering the table values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDiff(const size_t cols, const int *arr)
{
    int max = 0, min = 0;
    if(arr)
    {
        max = arr[0]; min = arr[0];
        for(size_t col = 1; col < cols; col++)
        {
            if(min > arr[col]) min = arr[col];
            else if(max < arr[col]) max = arr[col];
        }
    }
    return max - min;
}

int main(void)
{
    int temps[][4] =  {
        {20, 27, 28, 22,},
        {12, 22, 12, 20,},
        {22, 24, 25, 33,},
        {33, 30, 30, 29,},
    };

    for(size_t row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        printf("Diff row %zu = %d\n", row, getDiff(4, temps[row]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the min and max *each time* in the `for(i)` loop.

Use `unsigned` math to avoid `int` overflow.

```
// Not needed
// int largeA = array1[0][0];
// int smallA = array1[0][0];
// int diff = 0;

for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
{
    //int diff = 0;
    int largeA = array1[i][0]; // add
    int smallA = array1[i][0]; // add
    for(int j=1; j<column; j++)
    {
        if(array1[i][j] > largeA)
        {
            largeA = array1[i][j];
        }
        if(array1[i][j] < smallA)
        {
            smallA = array1[i][j];
        }
    }
    // diff = largeA - smallA;
    unsigned diff = 0u + largeA - smallA;
    // printf("%d\n", diff);
    printf("%u\n", diff);
}
```

Comment: It helped me. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll never encounter integer overflow with temperatures

Comment: @AlanBirtles Good coding practices with small tasks avoid [big bad ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure) - your call.